# Facebook Share og:image is blank when using https

Tags: image, facebook, https, share, cdn

It tried to use HTTPS with og:image but the image is blank with Facebook Share

safe_image.php returns this error (x-error-detail) :
x-error-detail  CDN request for an invalid safe image:

[image]

I have no error on the Facebook debug tools.

Any advice ?

Comment: _“Any advice ?”_ – any actual relevant _details_? Example URL?

Comment: URL example : https://www.koreus.com/video/chute-supercross-jeremy-martin.html
Og:image : https://thumbshigh.koreus.com/201701/chute-supercross-jeremy-martin.jpg

Comment: [Debugging the image URL directly](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fthumbshigh.koreus.com%2F201701%2Fchute-supercross-jeremy-martin.jpg) shows an error, _"Could Not Connect To Server - Check that the webserver is running, and that there are no firewalls blocking Facebook's crawlers."_

Answer (score 0):

Here's a checklist that might or might not help you with it:

1. Is the content behind Basic Auth?
2. Is the content inaccessible by Facebook crawlers because of robots.txt? [More info](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler)
3. Is the site on a VPN or is it publicly available?

As @CBroe suggested, try running the image URL directly into the scraper, and just in case click Scrape again. Once you see the image being crawled properly there, there's no guarantee Scrape Again on the page that was using it as `og:image` will get fixed. This happened to me... My hard guess, it's a load balancing issue between their image crawlers (safe_image.php)

Edit: I fixed my case by realizing I was missing a tag. Yes. Missing a tag on a `og:type` video, and Facebook was just removing the thumbnail instead of saying "missing a tag bruh"

Make sure you see all the following 5 properties in the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) for `og:video`:

```
url
secure_url
type
width
height
```